# TCP Socket communication with unity

Tags: c#, unity, socket

I am working on communicating unity application with an PC app. Since I doesn't know how socket programming can be implemented in unity.Can anybody please help me in creating a simple small application using TCP socket with unity

Answer (score 1):

Unity has two different networking subsystems: The old but still available [Legacy Networking API](https://web.archive.org/web/20170607234112/https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NetworkReferenceGuide.html) and the [New UNET Networking API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetOverview.html). But both are high-level APIs designed around the Unity engine and don't offer low-level TCP/IP functionality (both are based on UDP). That means you can't use them to interface with something not developed in or specifically for Unity, especially not something which expects a TCP connection.

You can also use the Unity class [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) to interface with programs which use a HTTP-based communication protocol (like [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), for example). But this class doesn't provide raw TCP sockets either.

However, nothing stops you from using the standard networking classes available in the .NET framework. Specifically the class [`Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) or the more high-level class [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and the class [`NetworkStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) are of interest here. Details about how to use the .NET socket classes aren't game-development specific, so you should ask about them on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+sockets). By the way: I haven't tried but I can't imagine that this works on platforms which don't have a low-level TCP API, like for example HTML5.

Comment: That's untrue about the new API. They expose functionality to work with the raw sockets (or as close as you can get which I wouldn't consider _high level_ at that point). https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html It also works with the HTML5 target by using WebSockets, so that's neat.

Comment: @Coburn I'm sorry, but you are wrong about that. [UNET is based on UDP, not TCP](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/11/all-about-the-unity-networking-transport-layer/). It doesn't even give you pure UDP, because it adds some TCP-inspired reliability features to it. WebSockets use TCP, but they aren't pure TCP either. They add a lot of framing and masking around it. Why is this nitpicking important? Because the OP wants to interface with an existing TCP application, which requires to accurately implement a TCP-based protocol.

Comment: Ah, I must've misread. You're still stuck in Unity's domain if you're using UNet, it's just lower level UNet and not raw sockets. I figured it would be to OPs benefit to know it exists depending on her usecase.

Comment: Might want to update this answer to recommend UnityWebRequest over WWW for HTTP communication.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, and there is also a lot more that has happened in Unity networking-wise since this answer was written. But I am a bit behind on keeping up with it, and I am not sure if it's worth it to invest the time to read up on all that for a 0 score answer to a 0 score question from 7 years ago.

Comment: Well now it's a 1 score answer so the Community bot won't keep bumping the question to the top of the feed. 

Answer (score 0):

I’ve successfully used standard c# UDP and TCP connections in Unity. The main issue is that you’ll need to have it on a separate thread. Which Unity hates. So you need to make sure you have threadsafe data structures that are passed between the main Unity program (main thread) and the data being streamed over the socket (other thread).

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a bit? Tell us which classes and language features you used to achieve this? Maybe show us a simplified version of your code?